# How do you reference the list of detail records in a trigger

Tags: soql

i have an MDR, and in the trigger on the master, and I'm trying to access the children.  how do you do that?

The detail is named pg_metric__c.  I'm referencing it as c.PG_Metrics__r

Comment: triggers only have context to the SObject being triggered, all other relationship fields upwards and downwards have to be queried for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to query any related records. Something like this would work:

```
for(Parent__c record:[SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT Id, ... FROM PG_Metrics__r)
    FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]) {
    // record.PG_Metrics__r contains the children
}
```

Comment: Ah, i thoguht it would come in for free, like the standardcontroller. In this instance and the standard controller there seem to be some differences in what you can acces without a query. Can you elaborate a bit? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66193/what-is-the-standard-controller-and-what-can-it-access . thanks @sfdcfox!